# Memory representation of Empty String

Tags: java, string, null

How is an empty string stored internally in the memory? I was thinking about an empty string memory representation and can't quite comprehend it. Is there some specific ASCII value for it? What is an empty string exactly?

Comment: If you know how a non-empty string is stored, then the answer becomes a lot easier to figure out. Check the source code in `String.java`

Comment: Well, a `String` object includes a reference to an array of characters.  How many characters would you expect to find in that array, if the object represents  an empty `String`?

Comment: for empty string i.e `""`  the space requirement is 0 because it is already present in string pool.

Comment: Read [String Memory Internals](https://dzone.com/articles/string-memory-internals) it is about this.

Comment: Here is [one implementation](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) of the String class in Java.

Answer (score 2):

A `String` object is a Java `Object` like any other. It is an object that has a length attribute, which ultimately is stored in a Java object as an `int`. An empty `String` has length 0, and thus that `int == 0`. In actual implementations, a `String` object internally has a reference to a `char[]` object (an array of `char`s).

For an empty `String`, that reference *might* be `null`. In *theory* the `String` implementation might always have a non `null` array reference, and use the length of the array of `char`s as the `String` length `int`, in which case you question would be equivalent to asking about the memory representation of an empty array.

See [the OpenJDK implementation](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) for example:

```
 private final char value[];
```

is the reference to the array of characters

```
 private final int count;
```

is the length of the `String`, as you can see for the default constructor, which creates an empty `String`:

```
 public String() {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = 0;
    this.value = new char[0];
 }
```

(You might be wondering why that implementation has an `offset`. This is so a sub-string can share the same character array as its parent string, which reduces memory use in many cases).

Answer (score -1):

- An empty string is a string whose length is 0. It is the same as
  a string whose length is greater than 0, for all of them are
  allocated with a memory block to store the variable.
- All the strings are readonly, that is to say, the memory block can
  not be resized after being initialized. In some code, we can see

  > str1 = str1 + str2

  but actually `str1` isn't being resized because of the copy-on-write rule. 
  The system re-allocates a new memory block to store the new result and
  changes the pointer of `str1` to the new one.
- In basic, the string is an array; the empty string is just a character array with no elements, length is 0, but there is no difference between an empty string or a non-empty string. Both of them have a memory address, the pointer.
- If you know the string indicator in C/C++, it is just a char * pointer, it always ends with a `'\0'` character. When you read a string, there will be a loop to move the char * pointer from the first address to the next one, until it arrives at `'\0'`. So the empty string in Java is just a char * pointer immediately followed by `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you. It made things pretty clear in my head :)

Comment: Good explanation. However, in Java, a String is an instance of a class and is not just a pointer to a sequence of characters. Also the sequence is counted, not terminated (at least from a Java coding perspective).

Comment: "So the empty string in Java is just a char * pointer immediately followed by '\0'.": that is incorrect. You can create a Java `String` that holds a sequence of NUL characters ('\0').

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem right to me at all.  How is an empty string the same as a non-empty string?  Of course the latter takes up more memory.  And the business about having `'\0'` next to a `char *` seems to me to be how some other programming language stores strings, not Java.